# Using array notation over pointer notation, and vice-versa

Tags: c++

From what I've seen, pointer notation and array notation have a significant amount of overlap. What is unique to each method of notation? In what situations would it be more beneficial to use one method over the other?

```
int main(){
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
    int * arrPtr = arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<arrPtr[i]<<" "<<*(arr+i)<<" "<<*(arrPtr+i)<<endl;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've explained it [in this blog post](https://ghost.pileborg.se/2016/08/28/the-difference-between-arrays-decaying-to-pointers-and-pointers-to-arrays/).

Comment: Minor typo in very good blog post. The Array is 4 long not ten. Thought you would want to know

Comment: _@TylrRC_ Could you please decide for a specific language? Answers may come out very different (and orthogonal).

Comment: One difference is that pointers can be modified, such as *(arrPtr++) = ... , or arrPtr += ... .

Comment: @rcgldr So arrays can't be modified in general?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - the address of the arrays can't be modified.

Comment: In the case of indexing, I've read that some C / C++ compilers translate array style indexing into pointer style indexing, which would allow an expression like 2[arr] to compile, as it's translated to *(2 + arr).

Comment: The C faq is an excellent resource for questions like this: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @rcgldr `x[y]` is defined as `*(x+y)`, if `x` does not have class type

Comment: @Quentin Hmm... I saw that a couple of hours ago and was going to fix it, but gut hold up doing something else. Fixed now though, thanks for the remainder. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Your blog post was very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An object of type T[N] knows what N is at compile time. An object of T* does not know how many T's are at the destination address.

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int* b = new int[10];

    std::cout << sizeof(a) << ", " << sizeof(b) << "\n";
}
```

outputs `40, 4` (http://ideone.com/GANFtB).

Arrays *decay* to pointers (see http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr), such that when you write

```
void f(int a[])
```

you're actually creating a function with a prototype of

```
void f(int a*)
```

at this point, you no-longer know the dimension of `a`.

However, pointers and arrays are designed to complement each other. When you have

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

`a` will gladly decay to a pointer for you

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p = a;

std::cout << a[0] << p[0] << *a << *p << *(a+1) << *(p+1);
```

will print `111122` (http://ideone.com/G61NL1)

Using a fixed sized array means:
- As a local variable, it will be on the stack. Advantages: speed, locality, disadvantages: size is constrained and size must be known at compile time.
- As a global variable: a fixed size allocation in the program binary, size required at compile time.
- As a member variable: increases the object size by a known quantity, size required at compile time.

Pointers allow you to allocate dynamic memory, but require you to pass along a size parameter:

```
void f(int* a, size_t elements);
```

With an array you can use tricks to write size-specific code:

```
void f(int (*a)[10]);  // require input to be an array of 10 elements

int a[4];
f(&a);  // error: int (*)[4] can't convert to int (*)[10]
```

and template tricks:

```
template<size_t N>
void dump(int (&a)[N])   // takes arrays with known size only
{
    std::cout << "[" << a[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << ',' << a[i];
    std::cout << "]";
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };  // compiler calculates size
    dump(a);
}
```

http://ideone.com/ATB81u

All that said, in neither case does the language implement bounds checking:

```
int main() {
    int a[10];
    a[100] = 1;  // compiles and links
}
```

You can get bounds-checked array access if you use `std::array` and the `at` operator.

```
std::array a<int, 4>;
a.at(20);  // detected as runtime error and not UB
```

Answer (score 0):

> In what situations would it be more beneficial to use one method over the other?

There's no difference actually, so we can't tell if there's any advantage for using the one or the other.

---

Rather use `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int,4>` regarding c++.

Comment: Erh - *no* difference between pointer and array?

Comment: @kfsone No difference regarding the syntax used in the OP.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that someone who needs the difference explained on SO would know to make such a clarification in their question? His example code seems to line up with his general question, it doesn't seem to establish purely concrete constraints on it.

Comment: @kfsone the question is asking about whether to access an array via the `[]` or `*` operators , not about the difference between pointers and arrays

Answer (score -1):

### `int arr[]` vs `int * arrPtr`

The difference between `int arr[]` and `int * arrPtr` is that the compiler "knows" that one is array and the other is a pointer ;)

For example:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int * arrPtr = arr;
cout << "sizeof(arr): " << sizeof(arr) << endl
    << "sizeof(arr[0]): " << sizeof(arr[0]) << endl
    << "sizeof(arrPtr): " << sizeof(arrPtr) << endl
    << "sizeof(arrPtr[0]): " << sizeof(arrPtr[0]) << endl;
```

Might print something like:

```
sizeof(arr): 16
sizeof(arr[0]): 4
sizeof(arrPtr): 8
sizeof(arrPtr[0]): 4
```

`arr[0]` and `arrPtr[0]` are the same thing, but `arr` and `arrPtr` are not. You can use that fact.

### Bounds Checking?

Arrays also give compilers a chance to do some bounds checking, but that is limited.

Static checks will work at least on some compilers. E.g. this does not compile in VCC:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
arr[4] = 7;
```

But there is no way to have protection against this:

```
arr[x] = 7;
```

There are also functions which implement run-time protection based on array size. For example, this does not overwrite memory after `s1`:

```
char s1[] = "aaa";
sprintf_s(s1, "sssssssssssssssssss");
```

It fails, because `sprintf_s` "knows" size of `s1` (the size is actually a template argument to [sprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)).

### `arr[i]` vs `*(arr + i)`

There is no difference between `arr[i]` and `*(arr + i)` for integer arrays. But for your own pointer-like-classes, you could override `[]` and `+` operators in a way which would make them different.

---

Comment: But does that mean anything? E.g bounds checking for the array?

Comment: This isn't really answering the question, which as far as I can see is about two alternative syntaxes for element access.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe... The OP mixed two problems and I noticed the one that seemed more interesting. I updated the answer... I hope I covered everything now :)

Comment: Recommendations: 1. "But there is way to have protection against this:

arr[x] = 7;" Leaves us hanging by not explaining what that protection is and how to use it. 2. Add in a reference to that 2 parameter sprintf_s. All the ones I know about require a length parameter and don't necessarily throw an exception.

Comment: @user4581301 1. "there is no way to have protection" was the intended phrase. corrected. 2. there is no exception. corrected also. But sprintf_s can take two arguments: `template <size_t size>
int sprintf_s(char (&buffer)[size], const char *format, ...)`, I added [link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)

Comment: @zvone Ah there he is. Didn't read closely enough. Thank you. Small caveat: I don't see that one in standard C++ so don't count on it being there when you need it.